# Finding the most general antiderivative or the indefinite integrals?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

A question in my Calculus book states, "Find the most general antiderivative or the indefinite integrals of the following":

$$ \int \left(  \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}-\frac{3}{x^4}+{4x}  \right)dx $$

Can someone walk me through how to solve this type of problem? I've just started  to get regular derivatives down, but going backwards I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What is $S$? Also, you can use `\frac{x}{y}` to make $\frac{x}{y}$.

Comment: S is my attempt at posting the symbol for Integral.

Comment: I've formatted the expression. Is that correctly written?

Comment: @OFRBG, yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the integral as follow:
$$\int\left( \frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2} - 3 x^{-4} + 4 x^1\right) dx$$
Now to integrate, you increase the power of $x$ by one, and then divide it by that power. For example,
$$ \int x^{-4/5} dx = \frac{x^{-4/5 + 1}}{-4/5 + 1} + C = 5 x^{1/5}  + C$$
Notice that there is a $C$ after the integration. $C$ simply represents a constant that can be determined if needed. It goes away when you take the derivative. Try doing the same with your problem. I hope this help.